# XPath expression

Tags: xpath, infoset

This question regards XPath expressions.

I want to find the average of the length of all URLs in a Web page, that point to a **.pdf** file.

So far I have constructed the following expression, but it does not work:

> sum(string-length(string(//a/@href[contains(., ".pdf")]))) div
>   count(//a/@href[contains(., ".pdf")])

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Which XPATH version you are looking for 1.0 or 2.0

Comment: The XPath version is not an issue: if someone can, he can solve the problem in both versions. Momentarily I am testing the expression using FirePath (in Firefox).

Comment: What should mean _XPath version is not an issue_. I do not think there is an solution for this with version 1.0. Also keep in mind that FirePath  does not even support complete version 1.0 (or at least has sum issues) if I remember correctly.

Comment: Post some input. Does your document include namespaces?

Comment: @JensErat You can assume that the document does not contain any namespaces. It should work on any valid HTML document (the structure is known in HTML -- **a** tags contains **href** attributes). I do not think the rest matters since the traversal can be made recursive.

Comment: Then you should be totally fine with the XPath 2.0 expression given in my answer. And "I've got some XML document" does not imply not having namespaces (XHTML), so this is an important question.

Comment: @hr_117 I mean that I am not constrained to produce the expression in one specific version. I just need it to work

Comment: I did not think it mattered so much -- my bad. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need XPath 2.0.

For calculating the sum of the string lengths, you will need either

- need a concatenated string of all `@href`s to apply to `string-lenght($string as xs:string)` (which only allows a single string as parameter), but `concat(...)` only takes an arbitrary number of atomar strings, not a sequence of those; or
- apply `string-length(...)` on every @href as @Navin Rawat proposed - but using arbitrary functions in axis steps is a new feature of XPath 2.0.

If using XPath 2.0, there are functions `avg(...)` and `ends-with(...)` which help you in stripping down the expression to

```
avg(//a/@href[ends-with(., '.pdf')]/string-length())
```

If you have to stick with XPath 1.0, all you can do is using my expression below to fetch the URLs and calculate the average outside XPath.

---

Anyway, the subexpression you proposed will fail at URLs like `http://example.net/myfile.pdf.txt`. Only compare the *end of the URL*:

```
//a[@href[substring(., string-length(.) - 3) = '.pdf']]/@href
```

And you missed a path step for the attribute, so you've been trying to average the string length of the link names right now.

Answer (score -1):

Please put something like:

```
sum(//a/@href[contains(.,'.pdf')]/string-length()) div count(//a/@href[contains(.,'.pdf')])
```

Comment: This is XPath 2.0, sums up the string length of the link texts instead of the URLs and fails for non-PDF-files _containing_ '.pdf' somewhere in their name.

Comment: I will try the expression again when I find a proper XPath 2.0 tool to use. Thank you all!